# how to get the xml tag value using UFT 12.0

Tags: qtp

I have a scenario to read the xml file tag value in uft

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes" ?> 
- <SUBCUSTBRK>
  <CONN NO="01415500228" /> 
  <AccNo NO="8500098" /> 
  <Site NAME="317009068" /> 
  <SiteLocDesc NAME="11098946" /> 
  <ServNumLable NAME="" /> 
  <Status /> 
  <Currency /> 
  <DOB>2015-03-26</DOB> 
  <InvNo /> 
  <DOBFrmt>2015 MAR</DOBFrmt> 
  <Month>March</Month> 
  <Week>2015 W13(MAR26)</Week> 
  <Day>Day 85</Day> 
  <Dur>1558</Dur> 
  <Calls>35</Calls> 
  <Amt>1.337</Amt> 
  <MinDate>2014-05-26</MinDate> 
  <MaxDate>2014-06-25</MaxDate> 
  <BS>SSBS</BS> 
  <ServInfo>1</ServInfo> 
  <ZeroCalls>0</ZeroCalls> 
+ <Country>
  <ROW Area="SPECIAL SERVICES (08)" ServType="PSTN" CallType="Unknown" AccessType="Indirect" Calls="35" Amt="1.337" Dur="1558" Int="0" Flag="1" StndCalls="35" StndDur="1558" StndAmt="1.337" EconCalls="0" EconDur="0" EconAmt="0.000" PrimCalls="0" PrimDur="0" PrimAmt="0.000" /> 
  </Country>
- <CalledNumbers>
  <ROW Num="08445768263" ServType="PSTN" CallType="Unknown" AccessType="Indirect" Calls="13" Amt="0.500" Dur="583" Area="SPECIAL SERVICES (08)" StndCalls="13" StndDur="583" StndAmt="0.500" EconCalls="0" EconDur="0" EconAmt="0.000" PrimCalls="0" PrimDur="0" PrimAmt="0.000" /> 
  <ROW Num="08445768260" ServType="PSTN" CallType="Unknown" AccessType="Indirect" Calls="2" Amt="0.106" Dur="125" Area="SPECIAL SERVICES (08)" StndCalls="2" StndDur="125" StndAmt="0.106" EconCalls="0" EconDur="0" EconAmt="0.000" PrimCalls="0" PrimDur="0" PrimAmt="0.000" /> 
  <ROW Num="08445768262" ServType="PSTN" CallType="Unknown" AccessType="Indirect" Calls="18" Amt="0.677" Dur="788" Area="SPECIAL SERVICES (08)" StndCalls="18" StndDur="788" StndAmt="0.677" EconCalls="0" EconDur="0" EconAmt="0.000" PrimCalls="0" PrimDur="0" PrimAmt="0.000" /> 
  <ROW Num="08445768261" ServType="PSTN" CallType="Unknown" AccessType="Indirect" Calls="2" Amt="0.054" Dur="62" Area="SPECIAL SERVICES (08)" StndCalls="2" StndDur="62" StndAmt="0.054" EconCalls="0" EconDur="0" EconAmt="0.000" PrimCalls="0" PrimDur="0" PrimAmt="0.000" /> 
  </CalledNumbers>
- <DETAIL>
+ <TRANSACTION Type="PSTN" ServiceType="PSTN" Calls="35" Units="0" Amt="1.337" Usage="usage" Duration="1558" DOB="2015-03-26" BS="SSBS" Acc="0" FileName="CMNP">
  <H1>PSTN</H1> 
- <H2>
  <C1 DT="Text">Call Charges</C1> 
  <C2 DT="Text">Rate Period</C2> 
  <C3 DT="Number">No.of Calls</C3> 
  <C4 DT="Number">Units</C4> 
  <C5 DT="Money">R.O</C5> 
  </H2>
  <SUB_SECTION Type="Unknown" CategoryType="Voice" RP="0" Calls="35" Units="0" Duration="1558" Amt="1.337" /> 
  </TRANSACTION>
  </DETAIL>
```

In this xml I need the values of Transaction tag ServiceType="PSTN" Calls="35"
so how can I read these values. Can any one help for me?
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done Through eith XMLUTIL in UFT or creating the XML DOM . Please find a example below .

```
XmlDom1 =CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XmlDom1.load(<xmlPath>)
Msgbox XMLDOM1.SelectSingleNode("//Transaction/@ServiceType").text
Msgbox XMLDOM1.SelectSingleNode("//Transaction/@Calls").text
```

Comment: Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.Async="false"
xmlDoc.load("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\8500098_20150326\SSBS_8500098_01415500228_20150326.xml")
value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Transaction/@ServiceType").text
msgbox value
value1 = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Transaction/@Calls").text
msgbox value1 but i am getting the error like.Object required: 'xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(...)'        value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Transaction/@ServiceType").text".  can u resolve it for me.Thanx in advance.even i am not finding selectsingleNode in uft12.01

Comment: Msgbox XMLDOM1.SelectSingleNode("/SUBCUSTBRK/DETAIL/TRANSACTION/@ServiceType").text

Comment: Thanx for ur help sai. i am using UFT 12.01 and i am writing script like this        Set xmlDoc =createobject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.LoadFile("C:\Newfolder\SSBS_8500098_01415500228_20150326.xml")
value = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Transaction/@ServiceType").text
msgbox value
value1 = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//Transaction/@Calls").text
msgbox value1 but i am getting error like this

Comment: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'xmlDoc.LoadFile'
Line (129): "xmlDoc.LoadFile("C:\New folder\SSBS_8500098_01415500228_20150326.xml")". even i tried this one with Xmlutil  i am no finding selectsingleNode method.

Comment: you need to use just load not loadfile

Comment: Thanx sai for ur patience. i am using Loadfile only but it is not working . i am not finding the selectsinglenode method.

Comment: can any one do it for me. i tried above methods those are not working in my UFT 12.01.is there any other  methods to do this.

Comment: share us the proper XML . with correct validation tags .I will share you the full code

Comment: i shared the above xml which i have.in that xml i have to read the callednumber tag in that tag i have to add all the Row tags Servtype and calls and i have to add the all the calls. can u do it for me. sai

Comment: in my UFT 12.01 i am not finding any selectsinglenode method and even microsoft.xmldom object is not creating in my UFT 12.01

Comment: any one do it for me.in my UFT12.01  XMLUTIL is only working.with this xmlutil how can i get the data of  ServiceType="PSTN" Calls="35" under TRANSACTION tag or  callednumber tag